# C# ZlibStream Write hangs indefinitely

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following piece of code to decompress data read from a MySQL database (the big bottleneck for this application is network speed, so decompressing server side is not ideal)

```
private static async Task<byte[]> DecompressBlob(byte[] y)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var decompressor = new ZlibStream(output, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {                
            await decompressor.WriteAsync(y, 4, y.Length - 4);
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The Write sometimes hangs on particular inputs until program is killed. The data is 100% fine - other applications that use python or C++ libraries to decompress the data handle it no problem. Additionally when I've fed it invalid data in testing it's fallen over with an exception rather than just hang.

I don't believe it's due to data length, as it handles longer arrays no problem. There is no difference I can see in this particular byte array, but it must be in the data as this problem is reproducible.

I've tried a different implementation too with the same problem:

```
    private static async Task CopyStream(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        int i = 0;
        while ((len = await src.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await dest.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        await dest.FlushAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<byte[]> DecompressBlob(byte[] y)
    {                                           
        // Convert to a stream
        var byteStreamCompressed = new System.IO.MemoryStream(y);

        byteStreamCompressed.Seek(4, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var byteStreamDecompressed = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        var zOut = new ZlibStream(byteStreamDecompressed, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
        await CopyStream(byteStreamCompressed, zOut);

        return yData = byteStreamDecompressed.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seem odd. The idea is to *write* to the stream when compressing, and *read* from the stream when decompressing. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zlibstream.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-io-compression-zlibstream-ctor(system-io-stream-system-io-compression-compressionmode-system-boolean)) for the stream given to the constructor of ZLibStream:

> The stream to which **compressed data is written** or from which data to **decompress is read**.

So try this instead:

```
private static byte[] DecompressBlob(byte[] compressedData)
{
    using var compressedStream= new MemoryStream(compressedData);
    using var decompressor = new ZlibStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    using var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream();
    decompressor.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
    return decompressedStream.ToArray();
}
```

Note that when dealing with in-memory data there is no point in using the asynchronous methods. Async is to optimize IO operations, and there are no IO going on here if you are starting with a byte array.

I'm not sure why you are trying to skip the first 4 bytes. If you are certain this is needed, just insert `compressedStream.Seek(4, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)` directly after creating the compressedStream.

Comment: The first 4 bytes are the length, think this might just be an internal thing.

Comment: Well, I have no idea why this works, but it does! Thank you.

Comment: @HarryAdams Added explanation & link to the documentation.